# MYSQL - how to perform second select if the firstone has no results?

Tags: mysql

How to get result in MYSQL:

If First Select has more than 0 rows return the result, else return result from the Second select (**not same tables**, only one column in both selects).

Something like
`SELECT IF ((EXISTS(SELECT Column1 FROM Table1)),(SELECT Column1 FROM Table1),(SELECT Column1 FROM Table2);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a union trick here:

```sql
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT Column1, 1 AS pos FROM Table1
    UNION ALL
    SELECT Column1, 2 FROM Table2
)

SELECT Column1
FROM cte
WHERE
    pos = 1 OR
    NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM cte WHERE pos = 1);
```

Comment: Coool ... thank you :)
I would expect there has to be easier solution but did't find any, maybe this is the easiest :)))

Comment: There are other approaches, but I don't know how to do it without scanning the table twice.